# Can I lock row of DB2 for reading?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, db2, ejb

I've few scheduled processes which perform on the same row. Actually this row is a SMS needed to be sent. First process is @Asynchronious process which invoked when I press send button and second process is @Scheduled process which invoked once per minute. After I've written a SMS into DB it has status 0. After I've successfully or unsuccessfully sent it, it will have status 2 or 3 accordingly. The problem that when I read a SMS from the DB2 but before I actually sent it the second process can read and send it too. So, my question how can I prevent it? Can I lock specific row for reading? Another way is to add additional status 'processing' and change this status when I read a specific row, but I doubt is is possible to read and to write simultaneously? I though also about global flag which will indicate that this process can't be run, but I'm not only looking for solution I also looking for the most correct solution. Thank you very much!

And sorry for my English guys, if somebody will edit it I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot reliably prevent other applications from reading a row locked by one application. Queries running with the **uncommitted read** isolation level will be able to access even exclusively locked rows. Queries running with the **cursor stability** isolation level using the currently committed semantics will access the previous version of the exclusively locked row.

I think your best choice is to use a special value (like 'processing') in the status column to prevent other sessions from processing the same row.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're using DB2 for Linux/Unix/Windows, since you don't mention a platform.

There is a way to have DB2 lock a row on a SELECT, see the `isolation-clause` and `lock-request-clause` on [this Information Center page](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000879.html?cp=SSEPGG_9.7.0%2F2-10-5-3).

When specifying an isolation level of either `RR` (repeatable read) or `RS` (read stability), you can also say that you want to lock the rows that are read, either with a `SHARE`, `UPDATE`, or `EXCLUSIVE` lock.

That statement will lock the row as long as the transaction is active.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I actually solved it by creating a singleton with following flag `public static boolean busy;` first method which run change its value to true and while it's true second method doesn't run. While first method completed it changes it back to false.

Comment: Be aware this can only work if you have a single server. Finding a DB solution is probably best. Note that with the right isolation levels, if you do a read of the row, then that will lock it for read for the duration of the transaction, and you can update it later. Alternatively, you can select-for-update to read with write intent.

Comment: Thank you for warning I'll try to implement this solution too.